# best way to quickly filter lines of a huge 69GB text file according to multiple patterns

Tags: python, grep

what's the best way to filter only lines in a file that match one of ~20,000 combinations? the patterns are \tZZZZ\t where ZZZZ is a number from a list I've created.

I've been using:

```
for i in `cat patterns.txt`;
do
echo "$i
cat large_file.txt | LC_ALL=C grep $i >> matched_lines.txt 
done
```

but it seems very slow. Python implementation is also terribly slow...

the large file looks like this (tab delimited, 3 columns):

```
31599   94722   0.0184520931023
31599   33175   0.021944980284
31599   95587   0.0181413842575
31599   93637   0.0184741548464
31599   32411   0.0122635750533
31599   55509   0.0145808169111
```

Comment: You should provide an example for some of the patterns and show us a few of the lines that can be found in your large file

Comment: can the patterns be represented as a group of regexes? (.*)((pattern1)|(pattern2)|...)(.*) and then just do a regex match on each line?

Comment: the large file will look like the edit above and all the patterns select certain numbers from the second column (the file is tab delimited)...

Comment: @sanchitarora I don't think the patterns can be represented that way, as they are all essentially selecting a given set of numbers from the second column...

Comment: from the grep manpage: "fgrep is quicker than both grep and egrep, but can only handle fixed patterns (i.e. it does not interpret regular expressions)." Perhaps you want something like "fgrep -f patterns.txt large_file.txt > matched_lines.txt"?

Comment: the fgrep seems to be indeed the fastest tweak to this... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed and bash:

```
sed -n -f <(sed -n 's|.*|/\t&\t/p|p' patternfile.txt) largefile.txt > result.txt
```

With GNU sed, grep and bash:

```
grep -f <(sed -n 's|.*|\t&\t|p' patternfile.txt) largefile.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: thanks, it's still extremely slow...  maybe I should split the large file into smaller ones?

Comment: Okay, split in smaller files and try it with several parallel sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge, I had determined many million patterns which I needed to match in a file with many million lines. The patterns in my case were strings that identified the records/lines I needed from the search file.

The pattern file was ~5.5 mil lines of patterns, 304MiB.
The file to search in was ~7.5 mil lines of json docs (one json doc per line), 25.1GiB.

So by my calcs, the loop iterations for this problem were over forty-one trillion.

```
7,500,000 * 5,500,000 = 41,250,000,000,000.
```

My logic being the 5.5 mil searches needed to be searched for in each line of the 7.5 mil lines/records.

The patterns in the patterns file were unique. So, I had an idea that for each time a pattern matched it could be discarded from the next search iteration, reducing the iteration count. I tried to implement something in python, but it was far too slow, even if I was to parallelise it later.

I'd appreciate if anyone can leave a comment to sanity check my logic/maths for this problem.

Here is the solution I came up with:

`fgrep -f` was an obvious choice but the ~300 MiB / 5.5 mil lines of patterns caused the kernel OOM killer to terminate the process very early on in the proceedings.

So I utilised [GNU parallels](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) tool to help chunk the patterns file as follows:

```
# create 7MB chunks (~100k lines/patterns per chunk), pass each chunk to fgrep -f
time parallel --tmpdir /dev/shm --pipepart --block 7m \
-a ../missing-eventIds-comm-quoted.txt --files 'cat' |
parallel --tmpdir /dev/shm -j4 -L1 --line-buffer '
  fgrep -f {} < <(exec 3<> /dev/pts/3; openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d \
  -pass env:SYMETRIC_KEY -in possible-missing-data.gz.enc |
  gunzip --stdout | pv -s7510130 --line-mode 2>&3 -N job{#} )
  # remove the chunk
  rm {}
' | gzip --stdout |
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass env:SYMETRIC_KEY > $matches.gz.enc
```

The `--files` option of `parallel` chunks the input into files and outputs the file names on stdout. So in the second `parallel` the `{}` template token is replaced by one of chunk filenames. Note the `rm {}` later on to clean up the chunks. In this invocation `parallel` searches the search file `n` times until all chunks are processed.

With my data this approach completed with 46 chunk iterations of the 7.5 mil line file. I specified `-j4` 4 parallel jobs The elapsed time was ~23 minutes.
The node was utilising `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6242 CPU @ 2.80GHz` vCPU's with `16 GB RAM`.

This approach kept `fgrep -f` memory usage nominal.

Clarification on the following:

```
< <(exec 3<> /dev/pts/3; openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d \
-pass env:SYMETRIC_KEY -in possible-missing-data.gz.enc |
gunzip --stdout | pv -s7510130 --line-mode 2>&3 -N job{#} )
```

This is an example of process substitution, but what about `exec 3<>`? I had a `tty` running on `/dev/pts/3` where I wanted to monitor the progress of reading the search file. So I opened this tty on file descriptor 3 `exec 3<> /dev/pts/3`. I utilised `pv` ([pipe viewer](http://ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)) to monitor progress in my `/dev/pts/3` session. This gave me a progress bar and velocity check for each parallel process. This is optional.